# 3 wire spa to gfci disconnect to main breaker

Tags: electrical

3 wire spa (no neutral/white) is connected to a gfci spa disconnect.  Within the disconnect, a white pigtail is connected from the gfci breakerto the neutral bus bar (separate from the ground bar). From the gfci disconnect to the main panel breaker (the 2 pole breaker in the main panel is NOT gfci) there are 4 wires.  To connect from the disconnect to the main breaker, does the white wire get connected to one of the (siver) terminals of the breaker (vs the gold terminals where the red and black are connected), or does it get connected to the neutral bus bar in the main breaker?

Comment: Pictures of all the things involved are _always_ helpful. You can [edit] them into your question.

Answer (score 1):

The white wire gets connected to the neutral bus in the main panel and to the neutral bus in the disconnect. It does not get connected to the breaker. The GFCI pigtail gets connected to the neutral bus in the disconnect and nothing get connected to the neutral terminal on the GFCI. Here's a nice little diagram from SpaCare.com that spells it out nicely.

[image]

Comment: That's what I thought.  When the electrician roughed it in, he connected all three wires to the terminals ... at the top of the breaker.  The neutral bar is at the bottom, and now the white wire is 24 inches short of reaching the bar.  Do I splice it, or ...?  I want to avoid having to spend $350 replacing the run from the disconnect to the main panel.

Comment: You can splice the neutral with a large wire nut.  Make sure you know which bus is neutral and which is ground.  Pictures are always nice.

Comment: Thank you, again.  I just found in the code book that splicing is allowed in the panel.  I already have my boiler running to the neutral bus, so know where that is.  Now on to the bonding ...